# messageDelete event and partials discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Lets say that I have a `messageDelete event` that I want to get the data from. Since I am required to have the `Channel` and `Message partials` for the messageDelete event to fire, the `message object` returned in the messageDelete event will be partial.

> When I'm trying to fetch this message, it returns an error saying that the fetched message is unkown.

So how can I get information like the `content` etc. from the `deleted message`?

My current code:

```js
client.on("messageDelete", async message => {
    if (message.partial) await message.fetch() // this is where the error occurs
    console.log(message.content) // will only work on non partial messages
})
```

Is there any way around this, cause it would be useful to get the information from past deleted messages.

**EDIT**

Toasty recommended that I use the audit logs, to which I have used the following code

```js
client.on("messageDelete", async message => {
    console.log(message) // seeing whats avaliable in the return
    if (message.partial) console.log("message was partial") // checking if the message was partial to compare with non partial messages
    if (message.guild) {
        const fLogs = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({limit:1, type:"MESSAGE_DELETE"}) //getting audit logs
        const log = fLogs.entries.first()
        let {executor, target} = log
        console.log("Message deleted by "+executor.tag+" in "+target) // responding.
    }
})
```

Output:

```
message was partial
Message deleted by CT-1409 "Echo"#0093 in 606323576714559489
```

So I can get the who and the (sort of) what of the message that was deleted.
I still cannot get the rest of the message information, as if I tried to fetch the message with the target id, it would give me Unkown Message again. But also when I logged the message object to start with, I noticed that there was a decent amount of information already present, which may mean some data would still be accessible from a partial message. I don't know how much, but perhaps enough for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

That you can't get any information of the `deleted message` is probably because the message..has been **deleted**.

As you can read [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/see-deleted-messages-discord/), this is **not** possible and would also be a **violation of the rules** and a **violation of the privacy** of users.

### But...

...if you have a `command` for deleting messages, you could get the information of the message **before** you delete it and do stuff with it

Alternatively, you could work with the [audit logs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#some-quick-background)

Comment: Yeah, I used to remember being able to get the information from the message object in the messageDelete event which didn’t seem to be working here. I’ll check our audit logs as I didn’t know that was accessible.